# Why is spring-core not including org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertySourceFactory

Tags: java, spring, maven

When I try to compile my project via IJ I get...

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertySourceFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
```

I am using an old version of Spring (long story can't upgrade rt now) but my maven dep looks like...

```
<spring.version>5.0.10.RELEASE</spring.version>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

What is missing? Do I need another dependency?

Comment: That should work; the class is present in that dependency. Something else is going wrong.

Comment: Show your dependency graph. Probably you use several Spring libraries.

Comment: @AndreiKovrov unfortunately I can't publish that due to proprietary dependencies. I can provide any spring related parts to the dependency graph. I will work on getting that up here asap.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- That is what I figured give me a little while to play some more and figure out the real problem and I will delete this.